# Geting an AxiosError of request failed with status code 500

Tags: node.js, reactjs, web, axios

Hello guys I'm building a simple task manager app and while trying to post data from the front page I got an AxiosError of request failed with status code 500. However, when I make the same post request in postman it works fine.
Below is my code

````
import axios from 'axios'
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import { Checkbox, Icon } from '@chakra-ui/react'
import {Text, Container, VStack, FormControl, Input, Button, InputGroup, Box, Grid, GridItem } from '@chakra-ui/react'
import { AiFillDelete } from 'react-icons/ai';
import {FiEdit} from 'react-icons/fi'
import {GrCheckbox, GrCheckboxSelected} from 'react-icons/gr'
import TaskBox from '../Components/taskBox';
import {useToast} from '@chakra-ui/react'

const Task = ()=>{
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
    const [taskName, setTaskName] =useState('')
    const toast = useToast()
    async function handleSubmitTask(){
        try {
            const config = {
                header: {
                    "Content-type": "application/json",
                },
            }
            const {data} = await axios.post("/api/tasks", {taskName}, config)
            
        } catch (err) {
            setLoading(false)
            console.log(err);
        }
        setLoading(false)
    }
    return(
        <header>
            <section className="container">
                <VStack spacing={'2.5rem'} className="box-heading" borderRadius={'.3rem'}>
                    <Text fontSize={'3xl'}>Task Manager</Text>
                    <FormControl display={'flex'} flexDir={'column'} gap={'1rem'}>
                        <Input 
                            type='text'
                            id='task'
                            placeholder='Enter Task'
                            onChange={(e)=> setTaskName(e.target.value)}
                        />
                        <Button bg={'blue.500'} color={'white'} fontSize={'1rem'} justifySelf={'end'} className='addTask' onClick={handleSubmitTask} isLoading={loading}>
                            Add Task
                        </Button>
                    </FormControl>
                </VStack>
                <article className="box-list">
                    <TaskBox />
                </article>
            </section>
        </header>
    )
}
export default Task```
````

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you simply Google "500 from webapp but 200 from postman" or the likes you'll find multiple posts about this on SO already, with issues ranging from incorrect/missing headers, to authentication issues, to payload issues and more. You need to use carefully compare the requests, there is obviously some difference somewhere, cos the API shouldn't care where a request comes from

Answer (score 1):

`header` should be in plural form and `Content-type` should be with a capital `T`:

```
const config = {
    headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
    }
```

Comment: I did this and it still didn't work. However, I am able to get from the database